# Run python processes in a semi-parallel approach from C#

Tags: c#, parallel-processing

I know similar questions have been answered before but my problem is a slightly different one.

I have a `Queue` of python files - python1.py, python2.py, python3.py, python4.py, python5.py
and want to run each of these files from a C# class.

But the complexity in here is I want python1.py, python2.py and python3.py to run in parallel.
And after the completion of the above  three tasks, continue executing the next two files sequentially.

How to go about this?

Is adding the three parallel tasks to a Task and doing a Task.WhenAll() a good approach ?

Comment: Are you OK with blocking the current thread while doing the processing, or you also want the whole operation to be asynchronous?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias The current thread can be blocked. Currently, I am dequeuing the parallel python files from the queue and executing them in a `Parallel.ForEach()`. It would be better if the total operation is async but not really required.

Comment: Using the `Parallel.ForEach` is fine. If the number of parallel operations is fixed, three in this case, you could also consider using the [`Parallel.Invoke`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.invoke) as a shortcut.

Comment: The number of parallel operations is not fixed.

Comment: Then just use `Parallel.ForEach`. You'll get the option to specify the degree of parallelism as a bonus, which is not possible with the `Task.WaitAll(tasks)` approach.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Thanks !!! So for the first three parallel tasks, I would use Parallel.ForEach and for the sequential tasks, I can execute them sequentially... Is this a good approach to follow ?

Comment: Yes, it is a simple solution, and simple is good I guess. :-)